# Azure VPN is not getting connected with SonicWALL VPN

Tags: azure

I have done below steps to establish a connection between Azure VPN and SonicWALL VPN using Site-to-Site connectivity:

1. created a Azure Local network
2. Created Azure Virtual network3.
3. Created Static Routing Gateway
4. Configured SonicWALL for the VPN connection to the Windows Azure gateway.

But still its not connected, it shows connecting status.

I followed below link:
http://jespermchristensen.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/creating-a-windows-azure-virtual-network-with-site-to-site-vpn-to-sonicwall/

Answer (score 1):

I've found that connecting a SonicWall with older firmware requires that I set the encryption type to AES 128 instead of AES 256.  When it was set to 256, the connection was very inconsistent and wouldn't stay connected long enough to complete a full domain controller replication scenario from Azure to on-premise.

Try these settings and see if they work:

**Proposals tab:**

**Phase 1**

Exchange: IKEv2 Mode

DH Group: Group 2

Encryption: AES-128

Authentication: SHA-1

Life Time: 28800

**Phase 2:**

Protocol: ESP

Encryption: AES-128

Authentication: SHA1

Uncheck "Enable Perfect Forward Secrecy"

Life Time: 28800

**Advanced Tab:**

Check "Do not send trigger packet during IKE SA negotiation"